# Missing reference for OpenRead method

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `OpenRead` method and running into error shown below,I did add `using.system.IO` in the code and in the references as can seen from the screen shot below?what am I missing?how to get rid of this error?

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    var zipFileName = @"C:\Temp\bins-9111.tar.bz2";

    using (FileStream fileToDecompressAsStream = zipFileName.OpenRead())
    {
        string decompressedFileName = @"c:\bzip2\decompressed.txt";
        using (FileStream decompressedStream = File.Create(decompressedFileName))
        {
            try
            {
                BZip2.Decompress(fileToDecompressAsStream, decompressedStream, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:-

```
'string' does not contain a definition for 'OpenRead' and no extension method 'OpenRead' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\gnakkala\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs  32
```

[image]

Comment: ZipFileName is a string - you want the instance of the file. Try  System.IO.File.OpenRead(pathToYourFile)

Comment: Shannon - I get the same error for `System` now....tried as `using (FileStream fileToDecompressAsStream = zipFileName.System.IO.File.OpenRead())`

Comment: If zipFileName contains the path and your file name like c:\myfiles\myfile.zip use File.OpenRead(zipFileName); Otherwise, you'll have to pass the full URL to your file like File.OpenRead(@"c:\myfiles\"+zipFileName);

Comment: Shannon - updated the question for zipFileName,its `var zipFileName = @"C:\Temp\bins-9111.tar.bz2";`

Comment: System.IO.File.OpenRead(pathToYourFile) works

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a System.IO.File method on string object. 
Try this: 
I changed the call to OpenRead to come from the File Object instead of string.

```
var zipFileName = @"C:\Temp\bins-9111.tar.bz2";
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(zipFileName))
 {
        string decompressedFileName = @"c:\bzip2\decompressed.txt";
        using (FileStream decompressedStream = File.Create(decompressedFileName))
        {
            try
            {
                BZip2.Decompress(fileToDecompressAsStream, decompressedStream, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Botonomous- How do I decompress in the same folder/file structure present in the .bz2 file instead of to a file?

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned by `@Shannon Holsinger` in the comments [OpenRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static method on [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) and NOT on string.

```
var zipFileName = @"C:\Temp\bins-9111.tar.bz2";
using (FileStream fileToDecompressAsStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(zipFileName))
{/* rest of code */}
```

See the [OpenRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation for more info.

Comment: Hi Igor - How do I decompress in the same folder/file structure present in the .bz2 file instead of to a file?

Comment: @kemosabee - ask another question using a new question on SO. Do not proceed to ask new questions through comments or completely changing the existing question.

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Not only for the question, but for any other questions that you would ask in future.